# Fluid - Baked Mesh is Shifted

Tags: mesh, physics, eevee-render-engine, fluid-simulation

When I bake my fluid data it comes out perfect but soon as I bake my mesh it gives me a wireframe of simulation and the actual fluid simulation right under it.

[image: fluid data baked]

[image]

And here is the one with the mesh data baked.

[image: Mesh baked]

[image]

How do I get it to where it only shows the finished baked mesh. I did this with a different fluid animation and when I check all the settings to this one they are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **Set origin to Geometry** for Domain object.
- Flow geometry you can hide from render in Outliner (Camera icon) and for viewport you can change Object Properties > Viewport Display > **Display as Bound** or Wire type, like that it is not hidden but is represented by different type.

[image]